# Symbol lookup error (undefined symbol) when deploying Qt5 app on clear Ubuntu machine

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5

I have a Qt5 application, compiled for release on Ubuntu. I prepare directory with:

- application
- all *.so libraries from `ldd` output
- `.sh` script from http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.2/linux-deployment.html

But when I run `.sh` script on another Ubuntu machine (without installed Qt5), I get next error:

> symbol lookup error: /path/to/app/./libQt5Widgets.so.5: undefined
>   symbol: _ZTI15QGuiApplication

How fix it?

Comment: Is it when linking your code? Do you have libQt5Gui.so.5 recognized?

Comment: no, it when I try to run application on another machine without Qt, and yes, I have all libraries resolved

Comment: Does the other machine also have this libQt5Gui.so.5? If not, you need to ship it, or statically link the application against Qt, I think.

Comment: I copy all needed libraries (including libQt5Gui) to the same folder as where application is stored

Comment: Hmm, strange then. Are you trying to run the application from the application's folder or somewhere else? Have you tried to set the library path just in case?

Comment: I'm running app using official script (given above) via both: terminal or nautilus

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but you need to do a bit of debugging if it does not work. :p